# Angular 6 - Dynamic url string with auxilary route

Tags: angular, angular6

I have a child route defined as:

```
{ path: 'training', component: TrainingComponent, outlet: 'history' }
```

The route works correctly when routing using this syntax:

```
<a mat-tab-link [routerLink]="[{ outlets: { history: ['training'] } }]">
        Training
</a>
```

However, I am loading these links dynamically from an api call, and this returns a string route of "/history/tab/(history:training)"

When angular generates the url it is correct, but I get the error: Error: Cannot match any routes.

Is it required to use the [routerLink]="[{ outlets: { history: ['training'] } }]" syntax, or is there anyway to pass the router link a simple string?

Comment: I'm making a guess here but try to make links absolute, i.e. prepend array with '/'

Comment: Thats what I am using. <a [routerLink]="'./' + node.data.url" >{{node.data.url}}</a>.  I can tell angular is generating the correct full url: http://localhost/en/history/tab/(history:training) , but its saying route doesnt work.  However, if I navigate directly to the route in the url, it works

Answer (score 0):

Hi Not sure but you can give `navigate[]` and `navigateByURL()` a try.
On click of the button call a method in your component and use any of these, it might help.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply, unfortunately doing it this way it would restrict a lot of benefits of using router link.  IE open in new tab, etc.

Comment: Have you given it a try? I think it would not restrict. Please just give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

```
<a mat-tab-link [routerLink]="['/parent',{ outlets: { history: ['training'] } }]">
    Training
```

I guess you have to pass on the parent also before the outlets are given child route